# Brackets - Support for Typescript goes crazy

Tags: typescript, brackets

I am using Brackets for Typescript coding, and I installed Typescript module by Martin Zagora, that can be found on the link:

https://github.com/brackets-userland/brackets-typescript

And it works pretty good. But, there are some crazy things that happen occasionally. For example like on the following picture. It detects error on line 1, and I do not see why would that be classified as error, the syntax look ok to me. Anyone knows what this can be?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Please define crazy because i'm not sure what you mean by crazy... Or do you mean the syntax error?

Comment: Good point, I edited question a little bit. Brackets gives error on first line, but I do not see why would this be error in TS.

Comment: try removing the space in front of the colon.

Comment: Nope, that is not the issue, I generally put spaces when defining variable, and usually there is no problem, or syntax error. There are only some specific situations, like these, and it is very strange.

Comment: Hmm, could it be a loaded module clashing? https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/19262

Comment: Shouldn't be, because I am not using any other modules in my project, they are not even installed, only one installed was TSC, via

npm install -g typescript